# Xcode 8 Beta crashes when loading project

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on my project in Xcode 8 Beta, and it crashed. All of a sudden it doesn't want to load my project. I've filed a bug report with Apple, but I thought maybe I should ask here in case there's something I didn't already try. I checked the xml on the pbxproj file and tried deleting xcuserdata.

Here's the output the crash reporter gives me:

```
Process:               Xcode [1180]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.0 (11160.22)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11160022000000000~6
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1180]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-06-21 18:24:01.546 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A201w)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        321BC13E-6B17-1F30-FBD5-C30BA2B450AB

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1542CA75-5F0B-4426-846E-83030A701AA1

Time Awake Since Boot: 2600 seconds
Time Since Wake:       370 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 8S128d
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -colorSpace not valid for the NSColor NSPatternColorSpace <NSImage 0x60800506cd40 Size={640, 920} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6080012ae7c0 Size={640, 920} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=640x920 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x608001e323c0"
)>; need to first convert colorspace.
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[NSColor colorSpace] (in AppKit)
  5   -[NSColor(IBColorAdditions) ib_isAnyGraySpaceColor] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6   -[NSColor(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) ibGetGenericGamma22White:alpha:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7   IBSPPlistStringValueForColor (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
  8  0x000000010af807ec (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
  9  0x000000010af93efa (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 10  0x000000010af7545c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 11  0x000000010af76a8c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 12  0x000000010af82ad1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 13  0x000000010af83ab1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 14  0x000000010af80573 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 15  0x000000010af839f1 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 16  0x000000010af755c3 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 17  0x000000010af8322c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 18  0x000000010af800ad (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 19   IBArrayByMappingCollectionWithBehavior (in IBFoundation)
 20  0x000000010af842a2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 21  0x000000010af80573 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 22  0x000000010af84085 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 23  0x000000010af8027e (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 24  0x000000010af8caff (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 25  0x000000010af836c2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 26  0x000000010af800ad (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 27  0x000000010af7ff31 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 28  0x000000010af43b41 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 29   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
 30  0x00000001174d53e2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 31   IBPopulateMarshallingRecord (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 32  0x00000001174ce129 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 33  0x00000001174cdee0 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 34  0x00000001174ccacf (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 35  0x00000001174d06c5 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 36  0x00000001174d0c68 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 37  0x00000001174d1f45 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 38  0x000000010af44b64 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 39  0x000000010af45054 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderWatchKitIntegration)
 40   _NSViewLayout (in AppKit)
 41   -[NSView _doLayout] (in AppKit)
 42   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 43   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 44   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 45   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 46   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 47   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 48   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeWithOldSize:] (in AppKit)
 49   -[NSView _layoutSubtreeIfNeededAndAllowTemporaryEngine:] (in AppKit)
 50   -[IBCanvasViewController editorStackDidChange:dueToOpeningEditorForObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51   -[IBEditorStack openEditorForObject:closingSubEditors:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 52   -[IBCanvasViewController openEditorForObject:closingSubEditors:scrollSettings:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53   -[IBCanvasViewController revertStateWithDictionary:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 54   -[DVTStateToken _pullStateFromDictionary:] (in DVTFoundation)
 55   -[DVTStateRepository _pullStateFromDictionary:] (in DVTFoundation)
 56   -[DVTStateToken _pullStateFromDictionary:] (in DVTFoundation)
 57   -[IDEEditorContext _applyEditorStateDictionary:forDocumentExtensionIdentifier:atDocumentURLToCurrentEditor:] (in IDEKit)
 58   __332-[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:]_block_invoke.1418 (in IDEKit)
 59   -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenNavigableItem:withContentsURL:documentExtensionIdentifier:locationToSelect:annotationRepresentedObject:stateDictionary:annotationWantsIndicatorAnimation:exploreAnnotationRepresentedObject:highlightSelection:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
 60   -[IDEEditorContext _notifyDelegateAndOpenEditorHistoryItem:previousHistoryItemOrNil:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
 61   -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorHistoryItem:previousHistoryItemOrNil:alwaysReplaceExistingNavigableItem:skipSubDocumentNavigationUnlessEditorIsReplaced:] (in IDEKit)
 62   -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorHistoryItem:updateHistory:] (in IDEKit)
 63   -[IDEEditorContext _openEditorHistoryItemFromStateSaving:] (in IDEKit)
 64   -[IDEEditorBasicMode _setPersistentRepresentation:forIdentifier:] (in IDEKit)
 65   __60-[IDEEditorModeViewController _setPersistentRepresentation:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 66   -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
 67   -[IDEEditorModeViewController _setPersistentRepresentation:] (in IDEKit)
 68   -[IDEEditorModeViewController revertStateWithDictionary:] (in IDEKit)
 69   -[DVTStateToken _pullStateFromDictionary:] (in DVTFoundation)
 70   -[DVTStateToken pullStateFromRepository] (in DVTFoundation)
 71   __32-[IDEViewController revertState]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 72   +[NSAnimationContext(DVTNSAnimationContextAdditions) dvt_nonAnimatedBlock:] (in DVTKit)
 73   -[IDEViewController revertState] (in IDEKit)
 74   -[IDEEditorArea _updateStateSavingRegistrations] (in IDEKit)
 75   -[IDEEditorArea _refreshEditorContextsAndPreserveCurrentEditorHistoryStack:] (in IDEKit)
 76   __31-[IDEEditorArea viewDidInstall]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 77   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
 78   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 79   NSKeyValueDidChange (in Foundation)
 80   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 81   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 82   _NSSetCharValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 83   __81-[IDEWorkspace _finishLoadingAsynchronously:shouldUpgradeFromSimpleFilesFocused:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 84   __81-[IDEWorkspace _finishLoadingAsynchronously:shouldUpgradeFromSimpleFilesFocused:]_block_invoke.349 (in IDEFoundation)
 85   __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in Foundation)
 86   -[NSBlockOperation main] (in Foundation)
 87   -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 88   __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 89   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 90   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF (in libdispatch.dylib)
 91   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ (in CoreFoundation)
 92   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 93   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 94   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 95   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 96   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 97   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 98   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 99   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
100   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
101   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
102   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
NSInvalidArgumentException
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your crash report into your question because link-only questions become useless when the links expire.

Comment: Actually, just managed to get it working by importing the project into Xcode 7, and then saving it. Running in Xcode 8 works 100% fine now!

Comment: You can make this a useful question by adding the crash details into the question and then posting an answer. You can then accept that answer after a brief wait. This will help anyone else that runs into the same issue.

Comment: Ahh, no problem! I'll do that right now! :) Thank you for being so nice!

Comment: If you have a way to reproduce this, filing a bug at bugreport.apple.com would be highly appreciated! Attaching the full Xcode crash file from ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and the storyboard/xib will help a ton.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by removing the Build and DerivedData folders relative to that project.

I keep the DerivedData folder relative to the project (you can set it in Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations) so it's easy to delete it.

Comment: My XCode 8 kept crashing after I open one of my projects but the crash log was different than the question. After I deleted all the subfolders inside DerivedData, the problem is also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just managed to get it working by importing the project into Xcode 7, and then saving it. Running in Xcode 8 works 100% fine now!