# Main storyboard error in xcode 8 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I try to build my project in Xcode8 beta, but I get this `storyboard` error. Also, I cannot open the storyboard. Xcode shows `The document "Main.storyboard" could not be opened. Could not verify document content` . The error prompts when I try to open.

> Main.storyboard: Exception while running ibtool: *** -colorSpace not valid for the NSColor NSPatternColorSpace

Comment: are you using latest ios ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955596/xcode-8-beta-crashes-when-loading-project

Comment: @AkshanshThakur what you mean by that? I have installed ios10 on my phone and i have the ios10 simulator too

Comment: @NitinGohel I tried that too. In xcode 7 its working fine. But still cannot build in xcode 8

Comment: Can you please attach the affected storyboard to a new bug at bugreport.apple.com? What platform is the storyboard for? Are you on macOS Sierra, or El Capitan?

Comment: Yes I can report a bug. Storyboard if for iOS Objective-C. I am in El Capitan.

Comment: Have you renamed the main.storyboard in any way? Have you cleaned your project?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue on Xcode 8 GM and I resolved it by doing the following:

1. Create a new storyboard.
2. Open your old storyboard as source code (via right clicking).
3. Select all and copy (cmd+A, cmd+C)
4. Right click on your new storyboard and open as source code.
5. Paste (cmd+V)
6. Right click on your new storyboard and open as Interface Builder - Storyboard

No idea why this works. It's the exact same file content. My guess is there's something cached in the workspace or project that's messing with Xcode's interpretation of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it.

I got an error like this when updating an Xcode 7 project to Xcode 8. Make sure that you let Xcode update everything in your project to current Xcode 8 standards.

To do this:

1. Open up your project
2. Go to Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax.
3. Accept all changes it suggests.
4. Clean Project ( Product -> Clean)

Please tell me if this does not work so I can try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I filed a bug report. Now the issue fixed in Xcode 8 final version.